# Static files errors after deploying Django project to Linux server

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am trying to deploy the django project to linux server but getting below

> error: Bad Request (400)

settings.py

```
    from pathlib import Path
    import os

    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    DEBUG = False
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'admin_interface',
        'colorfield',

        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'employee',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join('employee/static')

    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

output of `collectstatic`:

> Error: Found another file with the destination path 'css/mystyle.css'. It will be ignored
> since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make
> sure every static file has a unique path. Please advise if any changes are required.

Comment: Which webserver you are using?

Comment: I am using Linux Server

Comment: Linux is OS. Web server means nginx or apache?

Comment: Yes we are using Nginx

Comment: Are you able to share you nginx conf?

Comment: It seems your `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` are same conatain same path it shold be diffrent try to rename your `STATICFILES_DIRS` like this `STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join('employee/staticfiles')`

Comment: i did the same .Then error comes: 0 static files copied to '/var/www/aquatecinnov_usr49/data/www/attrendance.aquatecinnovative.com/attrendance/empmanagement/empmanagement/static', 189 unmodified.. python manage.py collectstatic is not working

Answer (score 1):

Most probably issue is with NGINX server configuraion. You wsgi app service static file but NGINX server not passing outside them on 80/443 port.

Try to change/add NGINX setting as below:

```
location /static/{
    autoindex on;
    alias /<your_path_to the_static_folder>/;
}
```